# Executing bash command in Intellij not working

Tags: java, bash, intellij-idea, openapi-generator

I have the following .js class located in my Project under "myproject/frontend/scripts":

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

function generateApiClientCommand() {
  return `java -jar ../../config/api/openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar generate
      -i ../../config/api/api.yaml
      --generator-name typescript-angular
      --type-mappings Date=string
      -c ../../config/api/config.json
      -o ../src/app/shared/data-access/api`;
}

function generateApiClient() {
  execSync(generateApiClientCommand(), { stdio: 'inherit'});
}

generateApiClient();
```

for creating open api frontend classes. Executing that script from generateApiClientCommand() in my bash is working without any problems but when this .js class is being executed during maven compilation, I get the following exeception:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ../../config/api/openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar
child_process.js:669
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Command failed: java -jar ../../config/api/openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar generate
      -i ../../config/api/api.yaml
      --generator-name typescript-angular
      --type-mappings Date=string
      -c ../../config/api/config.json
      -o ../src/app/shared/data-access/api
```

That .jar is located here: "myproject/config/api"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Print out the current working directory, then you will see the difference.

Comment: The path has to be relative to the current dir (`pwd` before you run the script), and you have to remove all the newlines from the command.

Comment: The path is correct as executing it in my git bash under "myproject/frontend/scripts" location is working. Also having it in one line is not doing any difference

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the myproject folder and ran this script then you should replace the ../../ become ./
Something likes this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

function generateApiClientCommand() {
  return `java -jar ./config/api/openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar generate
      -i ./config/api/api.yaml
      --generator-name typescript-angular
      --type-mappings Date=string
      -c ./config/api/config.json
      -o ./frontend/src/app/shared/data-access/api`;
}

function generateApiClient() {
  execSync(generateApiClientCommand(), { stdio: 'inherit'});
}

generateApiClient();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that mentioned .js file is located under "myproject/frontend/scripts" so that this path has been correct

Comment: Even though that js file located in "myproject/frontend/scripts" but if you are in myproject folder and execute that script then the path should be ./
e.g. You are in myproject folder and execute the script something like this:
node frontend/scripts/yourscript.js